# Can't Access has_many Association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a user has_many roles

```
has_many :roles
```

and a role belongs to user

```
belongs_to :user
```

then why

```
role.user ||= User.create(name: "moeabdol")
```

doesn't build the associaition between user and role

```
irb> role
user_id: 1
type: "admin"

irb> role.user
id: 1
name: "moeabdol"
```

and now this

```
irb> me = role.user
irb> me.roles
[]
```

returns an empty array!

Is this the expected behaviour? And if so then how can I build the association given that I have to create the role before the user?

Comment: Maybe the `roles` association is getting cached. Does `me.roles.reload` return an empty relation as well?

Comment: @Magnuss I tried reloading the association, still didn't work

Comment: What is `me` after `irb> me = role.user`?

Comment: I got it! role.user ||= User.create(name: "moeabdol") builds the association in memory. I still have to save the role after (role.save). Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

```
role.user ||= User.create(name: "moeabdol")
```

will only create a new user and assign in to the memory object, but your role object will still have a nil value in user_id

**What you need is something like:**

```
role.user ||= role.create_user(name: "moeabdol")
```

create_user is one of the belongs_to association method (look for create_association(attributes = {}) [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html))

Comment: The way I did it  role object does get assigned a user_id. And create_user doesn't save role to database. It only saves an new record of user and assigns its id to the role. I still have to manually call role.save

Comment: Is there a way I can have a one-liner where I create a user and save the role at the same time

Comment: perhaps i don't fully get you here but `obj.create_association` does create a new record and saves reference to parent obj. So a new user is created for the role then role updated with reference to the new user! isn't this your goal?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. That is my goal; however, it doesn't save user_id to role's record in the database. Only in memory. I tried it to confirm. I even tried create_user!

Comment: Aha, i get you know, but, i am sorry but i have no clue why this is happening!! plz let me know if you find explanation and solution!